# Why do I have backend in Google App Engine if I don't have backends.yaml at all

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml, backend

When I open the admin panel of Google App Engine I see that I have running backend. I didn't intend to have one and I don't have backends.yaml file in my config.

I doubt it is because in the app.yaml I have this line manual_scaling in order to be able to make longer operatiotns:
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

Probably I should consider using modules. But first I want to clear this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual scaling only works with "B"-type instances, which used to be known as "backend instances":

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class

Comment: Thank you Andrei. Then probably best for my case is to define 2 modules - one default for frontend requests and one for the big operations like importing a whole spreadsheet into the database? (That was the reason to choose manual scaling)

Comment: Correct, but look at the scaling options. You don't want your B instance to run all the time.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's the answer of another question I've wondered about. Even with no requests the instance had backend hours billed. Then I guess basic scaling is better choice for me because the instance will run until the task is completed and then shut down if idle.

Comment: Accept my answer if it answered your question. This is a way to tell other SO users that a problem has been solved.

Comment: Yes it answered my question. Now I know what to do. Thanks Andrei :)